# How to create Top navigation bar in Android TV using Leanback library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tv, leanback

We are developing the one Android TV application using Leanback library and we wanted to design the Top navigation menu bar instead of the default Left side Menu bar provided by Leanback design.

It is possible to create Top Navigation Menu bar using Leanback library.

Please find the sample image for what I am trying to achieve.
https://www.firesticktricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/sling-tv-firestick-11.jpg

Comment: Did you find solution, can you please share with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this repo on github. Link here - [TVLeanBackApp](https://github.com/zhangtiansheng/TVLeanBackApp). It has top horizontal navigation and refreshes RowsFragment on selection. Customise it as per your needs.

Comment: HI @Arpit J. I have followed your GitHub example tvnavigationmenu i need small help  I want to add  fix open drawer when we click on  any navigation item can you please help me in this Thanks

Comment: i want to always  keep an open drawer I want to show text and image in the same manner that we are displaying when the focus change left and open the navigation drawer